# How to broadcast Pandas groupby result to all rows?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Using Pandas 1.0.1, given this demo dataframe I want to substitute the numeric columns weight and price with their median values calculated on the subgroup 'box' (without modifying the original dataframe):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'box': ['a100','a100','a100','a200','a200','a300','a300','a300','a300'], 'id_in_box': ['2x', '1x', '3x', '2x', '1x', '3x', '1x', '2x', '4x'], 'weight': [2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 8, 6, 4.5], 'price': [1.5, 3.2, 2.1, 3.3, 1.5, 3.2, 2.1, 3.3, 4.4]})
df
    box id_in_box  weight  price
0  a100        2x     2.0    1.5
1  a100        1x     1.0    3.2
2  a100        3x     2.0    2.1
3  a200        2x     3.0    3.3
4  a200        1x     4.0    1.5
5  a300        3x     2.0    3.2
6  a300        1x     8.0    2.1
7  a300        2x     6.0    3.3
8  a300        4x     4.5    4.4
```

Actual:

```
df.groupby('box')[['weight', 'price']].transform(lambda x: np.median(x))
   weight  price
0    2.00   2.10
1    2.00   2.10
2    2.00   2.10
3    3.50   2.40
4    3.50   2.40
5    5.25   3.25
6    5.25   3.25
7    5.25   3.25
8    5.25   3.25
```

Expected:

```
    box id_in_box  weight  price
0  a100        2x     2.00   2.10
1  a100        1x     2.00   2.10
2  a100        3x     2.00   2.10
3  a200        2x     3.50   2.40
4  a200        1x     3.50   2.40
5  a300        3x     5.25   3.25
6  a300        1x     5.25   3.25
7  a300        2x     5.25   3.25
8  a300        4x     5.25   3.25
```

How can I achieve this in the most efficient way?

Comment: I don't want to modify the original dataframe. Do I need to create a copy before running the grouping operation and then assign the result to this copy? Is it the only way to generate this result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
new_df = df[df.columns[:2]].merge(
              df.groupby('box', as_index=False)[['weight', 'price']].median(),
              how='left')
```

Result:

```
    box id_in_box  weight  price
0  a100        2x    2.00   2.10
1  a100        1x    2.00   2.10
2  a100        3x    2.00   2.10
3  a200        2x    3.50   2.40
4  a200        1x    3.50   2.40
5  a300        3x    5.25   3.25
6  a300        1x    5.25   3.25
7  a300        2x    5.25   3.25
8  a300        4x    5.25   3.25
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to combine the 2 outputs in some fashion (as mentioned in the comments). Copying works (as you suggested) but would require 2 lines of code:

```
df_new = df.copy()
df_new[['weight', 'price']] = df_new.groupby('box')[['weight', 'price']].transform(lambda x: np.median(x))
```

A single line solution without overwriting the original dataframe is via join, albeit not as efficient for large data:

```
df_new = pd.merge(
    left=df[['box', 'id_in_box']],
    right=df.groupby('box')[['weight', 'price']].median(),
    left_on='box',
    right_index=True
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a primitive approach.

```
gb = df.groupby(['box'])['weight'].transform(lambda x: np.median(x))
gb1 = df.groupby(['box'])['price'].transform(lambda x: np.median(x))

df['weight'] = gb
df['price'] = gb1
```